# Referring to the artifactId of a maven dependency jar from persistence.xml

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, pom.xml

We're working with JPA and are trying to stick to standard spec (and avoiding Hibernate-specific features).

We use one project (let's call it X) inside another project (A) as a Maven dependency.

We need JPA to scan project X for Entities as well as scanning project A.

To that end, we've added a line

```
<jar-file>lib/X-v5-4.0.jar</jar-file>
```

inside

```
<persistence-unit>
```

in persistence.xml. This works fine.

The issue we still have is that we now need to specify the version of project X in not only pom.xml but also in persistence.xml. This is a recipe for problems with deploys in the future.

We've come up with a system using Maven resource filtering:

```
<jar-file>lib/X-v5-${x-version}.jar</jar-file>
```

in persistence.xml and

```
<properties>
  <x-version>4.0</x-version>
</properties>
```

and ${x-version}
in pom.xml.

This works but is still not perfect, as we'll have to remember to update the version number in a non-standard location each time project X gets a new version.

Ideally, we'd like to have a situation where we can adjust version information in the dependency part of pom.xml and changes would propagate to persistence.xml automatically. We'd reduce a lot of possible errors in future deploys this way.

Is this possible?

EDIT (OUR SOLUTION):

we have added a file named jpa.xml. We define an entityManagerFactory, a persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor and a transactionManager in it. The important part here is the entityManagerFactory bean. It has a property "packagesToScan" that allows you to indicate specific packages to scan for entities to put in the persistence context.

A code snippet:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jpaDataSource" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>org.com.our.external.library.package1</value>
            <value>org.com.our.external.library.package2</value>
            <value>org.com.our.external.library.package3</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm sure you see the advantage: as we are referring to these libraries by package signature, we no longer have to worry about jar version numbers.

Comment: I've run into the same situation with my project.  Did you ever find a good solution for this issue?

Comment: @EricB. I have added the solution as an edit to my question. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using the same thing as well, with the caveat that it is not a JPA standard.  But I gave up on the JPA standard solution.  I did find a plugin called `jpa-maven-plugin` (http://ljnelson.github.io/jpa-maven-plugin/) that you can use to update the persistence.xml file during a maven build.

Comment: this is still not working for me, did you have to change something for the JPA.XML to be used?

Comment: There is a more recent fork for the jpa-maven-plugin here: https://github.com/iSnow/jpa-maven-plugin

Answer (score 3):

I have solved it this way:

in `persistence.xml` substitute the whole `<jar-file>` tag, i.e.

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit">
    ...
    <!-- here is where the jar file is supposed to go -->
    ${importjarfile}
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```

Finally, set your properties like this:

```
<properties>
    <x-version>4.0</x-version>
    <importjarfile><![CDATA[<jar-file>lib/X-v5-${x-version}.jar</jar-file>]]></importjarfile>
</properties>
```

In this way Eclipse won't see the `jar-file` tag and won't complain.

My solution was actually a little bit cleaner since I was using a `.properties` file so I didn't have to use CDATA, I hope it still works.

My solution:

```
importjarfile = <jar-file>lib/X-v5-${x-version}.jar</jar-file>
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you add a unit test to verify that the `jar-file` as expected by `persistence.xml` is in fact in place?

It won't work to derive the version number in `persistence.xml` from a `dependency`.

It would work the other way around, thus to set `dependency.version` from the property in the POM. This satisfies your requirement to define the version only in one place and developers who want to update the `dependency` are likely to encounter the property, check it out and update the property rather than overwriting it with the updated version number.

This could be further supported by the [Versions Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/).

Comment: see my answer. of course in the pom you will still have to set the dependency to project X to see the classes, but the jar is only needed when building the project, and in that situation maven will perform the filtering